# How to show that P(A & B^c) =P(A) - P(A & B)?

Tags: probability

I can work out from a Venn diagram that:

$$ P(A \cap B^c) = P(A) - P(A \cap B)$$

Where A, B are sets and P is the probability function.

However I want to derive this using basic properties of sets and the probability function.

I have tried proceeding as follows but this does not seem to complete the proof:

$$ P(A \cap B^c) = P(B^c | A)P(A) .... ??$$
$$ P(A \cap B^c) = P(A | B^c)P(B^c) = P(A | B^c)(1 - P(B)) .... ??$$

Can you help me demonstrate the equality above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start off by writing out the seemingly silly decomposition $A = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)$. Apply the probability function to both sides, use the fact that the union is disjoint, and rearrange :)

Comment: That's the leap of faith I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A$ is the disjoint union of $A \cap B^c$ and $A\cap B$. Conclude using countable additivity.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I'll write $P(AB)$ for $P(A \cap B),$ and so on.

$$P(A) = P(AB \cup AB^c) = P(AB) + P(AB^c).$$

Draw a Venn Diagram. Give reasons for each step.
Then finish it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you prove that $A \bigcap B^{c}=A-(A\bigcap B)$

suppose $x\in A \bigcap B^{c}$ and prove that  $x\in A-(A\bigcap B)$.

after that , suppose $x\in A-(A\bigcap B)$  and prove that  $x\in A \bigcap B^{c}$.